# Java application is not connecting with Postgres Database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I recently setup a java application in my spring-boot. I'm getting this error when i run it:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ........
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres ........
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
```

2023-02-03 17:24:15 - Application run failed

My application-dev.properties file in src/main/resources/ has this code:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sofra_hybrid_7?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

I have made the database too as well in the postgres server with username "postgres" and pass "admin:

```
lalarukh=# CREATE DATABASE sofra_hybrid_7;
CREATE DATABASE
lalarukh=# grant all privileges on database sofra_hybrid_7 to postgres ;
GRANT
```

I have even also used the jdbc postgres jar file inside the application to make the connection but all in vain.
Seeking Help!

I can't run my java application as postgres can't make connection with my app in spring boot.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Hard without the full trace but it seems that you are not loading the dev properties as it seems to try to connect to another URL than the one you show. Are you sure you start with the correct profile?

Comment: `java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres`, but **application-dev.properties** , use jdbc:postgresql://**localhost**:5432, In most cases **localhost** cannot lead to **Unknown Host Exception**. So are you sure your application is using application-dev.properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue and after a lot of working I finally resolved it this way:
As you're receiving unknown host means that your application can't detect your this file: **application-dev.properties**

You shall make this **application.yml** inside your project (yourprojectdirectory/application.yml) and this will automatically detects the DB information and all.
As you're using postgres as DB so, add this code inside this file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql:db_name
    username: your-postgres-username
    password: your-postgres-password
```

Run this command for application running: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles`